# Mock patch path to function

Tags: python, mocking, patch

Is there a more easy way to get this path when mocking functions?

@mock.patch('folder1.folder2.file.class.get_some_information', side_effect=mocked_information)

I would like to have the path for the function get_some_information generated automatically. Thanks!

Comment: I've created a helper library that generates the paths in the pytest mocker syntax which is pretty similar, you might be able to employ it for your needs. See https://github.com/pksol/mock_autogen#generating-the-arrange-section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helper package to generate paths for mocking: github.com/pksol/mock_autogen#generating-the-arrange-section

Answer (score 0):

If you have the function object `get_some_information`, you can generate the said path by joining with a dot the object's `__module__` attribute, for package name and module name, and the `__qualname__` attribute, for class name and function name:

```
'.'.join(get_some_information.__module__, get_some_information.__qualname__)
```